# Como criar um Type de função no Typescript

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com React+TS, pesquisei bastante para tentar resolver antes de postar aqui, acho que preciso criar um Type para o parametro que eu passo na função `onSubmit` que é recebida como `Props` do `Mainpage.tsx`.

**O erro recebido é:**
*( onde ele foi gerado esta marcado no código abaixo )*

```
(property) onSubmit: (name: string, email: string) => void
Type '{ onSubmit: (name: string, email: string) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((param?: any, param2?: any) => void)'.
  Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((param?: any, param2?: any) => void)'.ts(2322)
```

**Form.tsx**

```
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react"

export const Form = (onSubmit: (param?:any, param2?:any)=> void ) => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log( 'Submit Form: ' + name, email)
        onSubmit(name,email);
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="name">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name..." value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="email">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email..." value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

**Mainpage.tsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "../../components/Form";
import { Greet } from "../../components/Greet";

const Mainpage: React.FC = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const onSubmit = (name:string, email:string ) => {

        console.log('Submit App: ' + name, email)
        setName(name)
        setEmail(email)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Greet/>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}/> **// O ERRO FOI GERADO AQUI** 
        </div>
    )
}
export default Mainpage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o erro seja gerado pelo fato das `props` de todo componente React ser um objeto e não apenas uma função de *callback*.

Algumas tentativas pode ser feitas para solucionar o problema. Criar uma interface para as `props` e incluir a função `onSubmit`, possa resolver esse problema. Ficaria algo assim...

No arquivo do `Form`, crie a interface:

```
interface Props {
  onSubmit: (param?:any, param2?:any)=> void 
}
```

Chame as `props` desta forma no componente:

```
export const Form = ({ onSubmit }: Props) => {...}
```

Veja o funcionamento [neste playground](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-sun-p9hr84?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou corretamente, e eu não sabia que as props de todo componente eram objetos.